# What is one word for that pregnant pause when a conversation shifts from light to serious?

Tags: single-word-requests

When the laughter dies away and there is an expectant moment before a more serious discussion or story begins?

Comment: Since you've tagged this as a single word request, you should include a sample sentence demonstrating how the word would be used.

Answer (score 1):

You may use **hush**:

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hush)
> Hush: a sudden, calm silence:
> deathly hush: *There was a deathly hush after she made the announcement.*
> hush falls: *A hush fell over the room.*

Merriam Webster gives
Hush: a silence or calm especially following noise

With an example relevant to your scene:
*a hush fell over the auditorium as the lights went down*

We might imagine:
*A hush fell as the laughter died away and the lawyer started his explanation …*